# Do We Need To Add Waterfall Source In Google Admob Mediation?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, admob

I am new in google admob mediation. I try to set up a mediation group for my application Android And IOS.

Please see this screenshot.
[image]

I have set up **Bidding Source** with No third-party SDKs required.

But I confused about the **Waterfall Source**

1. Is it a must to add waterfall source ? or I just can
   **skip** and Save Change ?
2. What exactly is waterfall source ? What its use for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Q : Is it a must to add waterfall source ? or I just can skip and
  Save Change ?
- A : If your app is new. Better just add waterfall source to
  gain more revenue beside Admob Network. Because some bidding source may doesn't approve your bidding. Because bidding is auction.

---

- Q : What exactly is waterfall source ? What its use for ?
- A : We can add new source network beside Admob Network. Check this link [Choose Network](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/choose-networks).
  If you got **ad serve limit**. The option is use other network to gain revenue. Ad serve limit **doesn't effect** other network.